# Conditional code in cellforRowAtIndexPath: not working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have some conditional code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. It appeared to be working correctly in iOS6 but then in iOS 7 the cell buttons have three dots hovering over them ... 
[image]

It also seems like they might be adding one button over another as each if statement's condition is met.

I have the following code after the if `(cell == nil) { }`
since I need to check the category id value for the conditional code for each table cell row

NSNumber *catId = [[self.listingNodesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"category_id"];

```
  if ([catId isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:9]] && (a == 0)) {
    cell.cornerImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellComprareCorner.png"];

    [cell.salvaBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_verde_commentsOFF.png"]
                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}


 else if ([catId isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:9]] && (a != 0)) {
        cell.cornerImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellComprareCorner.png"];

        [cell.salvaBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_verde_commentsON.png"]
                                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}



 if ([catId isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:9]] && (b == 0)) {

     [cell.likeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_verde_likeOFF.png"]
                              forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }


 else if ([catId isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:9]] && (b != 0)) {

     [cell.likeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_verde_likeON.png"]
                              forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }



 if ([catId isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]] && (a == 0)) {
            cell.cornerImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBlueCorner.png"];

            [cell.salvaBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_blu_commentsOFF.png"]
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }


        else if ([catId isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]] && (a != 0)) {
            cell.cornerImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellComprareCorner.png"];

            [cell.salvaBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_blu_commentsON.png"]
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }



        if ([catId isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]] && (b == 0)) {

            [cell.likeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_blu_likeOFF.png"]
                                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }


        else if ([catId isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]] && (b != 0)) {

            [cell.likeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_blu_likeON.png"]
                                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
```

Comment: Your conditional code looks fine (if we ignore all those magic numbers around), i think the problem must come from somewhere else!

Comment: thanks! is it possible that it's adding a uibutton on top of a uibutton in the table view cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that your button title is removed from XIB file. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the Button Title Text in your XIB file.

Those three dots appear because the button title text is bigger than the Button size so the ellipsis appear.

Comment: I removed the titles in the btns in the XIB and even disabled them but they still appear. Is there a way to explicitly set the title to nil or something? I tried cell.salvaBtn.title = @"";

Comment: I've removed the titles form XIB and everything looks fine. Are you sure you removed the titles from all button states? Each state has its own title. You can check that on Interface builder too.